# Fullcalendar : Display two month from today

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using full calendar with timeline view and from now I display 2 months ( june-july or september-october)

I would like to display two month from today's date :

Ex: Today : 05/09/2018
I want to have the september month and the october month

But if we are in october i want to have october and november instead of november-december

I don't know if I'm clear in my question

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your current code, because as far as I know fullCalendar does this by default. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultDate. This setting represents "The initial date displayed when the calendar first loads." And it says that "When not specified, this value defaults to the current date.". So if you don't set it, it will always load the calendar with a date range which includes today's date.

Comment: Thank I've just resolved the issues !